# where are expressions getting converted to expression trees and are solved?

Tags: python, expression-trees, sympy

I am debugging sympy module on how are expressions getting evaluated
and i used a simple code given below:

```
    from sympy.abc import x,y,z
    ee = x+y+x
    print(ee)
```

and kept a breakpoint at 2nd line and the next function it goes is to

```
    def __sympifyit_wrapper(a, b):
```

inside decorators.py with 'a' as x, 'b' as y and func as Add.
Can anyone tell me which file is assigning a and b here and what is running in the background.

Comment: Start with reading the definitions of `x`, `y`, and `z` in `sympy.abc` (I assume they're all instances of some abstract base class)

Comment: those are initialized to Symbol class i can manually do it with x,y = symbols('x y')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x`, `y`, and `z` are all `sympy.core.symbol.Symbol` objects. `Symbol`s are derived from `sympy.core.expr.AtomicExpr`, which in turn derives from `sympy.core.expr.Expr`.

Calling `x+_` (where `_` is anything at all) calls the associated `__add__` function, which is decorated with `sympy.core.decorators._simpyfyit`, which in turn is a simple wrapper around `sympy.core.decorators.__simpyfyit`, which is the function you see running in your breakpoint (the first bit of executed code)

Comment: The only logical leap here was knowing that `foo+bar` calls `foo.__add__(bar)`. What is it that you're trying to do that you either can't dig through source code or haven't learned about dunder methods, but you're trying to unravel the inner magic of sympy?

Comment: yes sir, now that you explained it is pretty straightforward.But as it is given in the documentation that every expression is converted to expression tree, i thought that the expression will be first converted to tree and the code traverses the tree to simplify it or convert it into canonical form.So, i kept that in mind and didn't understand the basic thing.